# COUNT values in PostgreSQL based on 2 conditions

Tags: postgresql

I would like to write a query in PostgreSQL for: The average number of Page Views per Session for sessions where a user returned to the website via the product page.

| Day | Time | sessionid | userid | page_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 14:16:15 | 709 | 696 | location |
| 5 | 20:18:49 | de1 | d8d | location |
| 13 | 15:58:23 | 199 | f4c | product |
| 13 | 16:00:07 | 199 | f4c | bookingDetails |
| 13 | 16:04:55 | 199 | f4c | product |
| 13 | 16:04:58 | 199 | f4c | other |
| 11 | 14:08:23 | 4c1 | 58f | product |
| 12 | 21:16:52 | ddc | bb9 | product |
| 12 | 21:17:38 | ddc | bb9 | product |
| 6 | 6:28:06 | eb3 | c57 | product |
| 6 | 6:28:10 | eb3 | c57 | product |
| 6 | 6:48:32 | eb3 | c57 | product |
| 6 | 6:48:36 | eb3 | c57 | product |
| 8 | 5:42:56 | 86b | c57 | product |
| 8 | 5:42:59 | 86b | c57 | product |
| 8 | 5:43:05 | 86b | c57 | bookingDetails |
| 10 | 15:48:53 | 6dc | c57 | product |
| 10 | 17:23:12 | 586 | c57 | product |

Comment: Please include the table information as text.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that, I changed it to a table. I hope it sounds comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

OK! As no one answered my questions, I finally found the answer on my own which you can find it as follows. Note that the answer has been written based on MYSQL not PostgreSQL. Besides, the following col names have been replaced:

session_id = sessionid, userid = user_fingerprint, page_type = page_views

Sorry, for any inconvenience! I didn't want to edit my initial.

```
SELECT COUNT(e.sessionid)/COUNT(DISTINCT e.session_id) 'PageViews/Sessions'
FROM page_views e
JOIN (
    SELECT a.PRIMARY_KEY , a.user_fingerprint, c.sessions_per_user, a.session_id, 
    a.page_type
    FROM page_views a
    JOIN (
        SELECT b.user_fingerprint, COUNT(DISTINCT b.session_id) sessions_per_user
        FROM page_views b
        GROUP BY b.user_fingerprint
    ) AS c ON a.user_fingerprint = c.user_fingerprint
    GROUP BY a.session_id
    HAVING (c.sessions_per_user > 1 AND RTRIM(a.page_type) = 'product') AND
    (a.PRIMARY_KEY NOT IN(
        SELECT MIN(d.PRIMARY_KEY)
        FROM page_views d
        GROUP BY d.user_fingerprint
    ))
) f ON f.session_id=e.session_id
;
```

It worked for me, I hope it works for you as well!